# How can i use azcopy in command to copy a file from Azure storage to AWS s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azcopy

I have a file in azure storage that i want to copy to AWS S3 using azcopy. I have tried the following. The file is called test.txt,
Azure storage account is called testsa,
Azure container is testsacontainer.
S3 bucket name is S3TestBucket

I have aws access key and secret.

```
   azcopy copy "https://<source-storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<file-path>;" "s3://<bucket-name>/<destination-file-path>" --source-credential-type "AzureBlob" --destination-credential-type "AWS" --destination-aws-access-key "<AWS-access-key>" --destination-aws-secret-key "<AWS-secret-key>"
```

I used the following :

```
azcopy copy 
"https://testsa.blob.core.windows.net/testsacontainer/test.txt;" 
"s3://S3TestBucket/test.txt" --source-credential-type "AzureBlob" 
 --destination-credential-type "AWS" --destination-aws-access-key 
 "<AWS-access-key>" --destination-aws-secret-key "<AWS-secret- 
 key>"
```

It gives the error: unknown flag: --source-credential-type

Is   just the name of the file.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Can you point us to the documentation that mentions `--source-credential-type`?

Comment: There are some examples on the [azcopy copy | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json) page that show files being copied between Azure and S3, but it talks about setting environment variables with the S3 credentials.

Comment: I just got it from chatgpt

Comment: so your help would be appreciated. Which command are you referring to ?

Comment: what is the easiet way of doing this process automatically ?

Comment: I know S3 well, but I am not familiar with using `azcopy`. I suggest you start by reading the [`azcopy` documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use AzCopy in a command to copy a file from Azure storage to an AWS S3 bucket?

As of now, This [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3) states you can only able to copy a file from AWS(s3) to Azure.

**Command:**

```
azcopy cp "https://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[object]" "https://[account-name].blob.core.windows.net/[container-name]/[your-blob-name]?[SAS]" --recursive=true
```

**`SAS`** is your Azure Blob Storage shared access signature, which you can get from the portal.

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Move your data from AWS S3 to Azure Storage using AzCopy | Microsoft Azure Blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/move-your-data-from-aws-s3-to-azure-storage-using-azcopy/)

**Update:**

I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment, It is not possible with **`Azcopy`** for copying from Azure blob storage to S3. Only possible with S3 to Azure blob storage.

Comment: Are you sure that this would work? AzCopy is for copying objects from S3 to Blob Storage and not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, @GauravMantri for guiding me correct direction. Updated the answer.

Comment: so what your saying is that it is not possible to automate the process of copying from Azure storage to AWS S3 in any way ?

Comment: It is not possible refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958544/how-can-i-copy-from-azure-to-aws