# How can i copy from Azure to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3

I have a file in Azure storage that i want to copy to AWS S3 bucket.
I want to have as minimal cost as possible.

I have copied from Azure storage to a local machine and then from local machine to AWS S3 bucket.
But I will be charged twice , copying to local and then to AWS.

Is there a way i can copy straight from Azure to AWS and have one cost ?
I am using the aws az cli and az cli for Azure.

UPDATE:
i HAVE A 150G file

1. SAVE IN AZURE STORAGE (COST) ?
2. Pull from Azure to local machine (COST) ?
3. PULL FROM LOCAL MACHINE TO AWS (COST) ?

whereas if i did the following

1. SAVE IN AZURE STORAGE (COST) ?
2. Pull from Azure Storage to AWS (COST) ?

The second scenario has one less action ?

Comment: There is no charge for uploading to Amazon S3, except for the PUT request (`$0.005 per 1,000 requests`). Azure seems to have a similar charge for GET. Azure also seems to have a `$0.02 per GB` charge for data going to the Internet. You would need to pay these costs regardless of _how_ the data is transferred. How did you calculate that you would be "charged twice"?

Comment: well i save to Azure storage 1st cost.  Then i download from Azure to a local machine 2nd cost. Then i upload , PUT to AWS 3rd cost ?

Comment: There is a cost for getting data from Azure. You need to pay that regardless of whether you "copy straight from Azure to AWS". There is a cost for putting data in Azure. You need to pay that regardless of whether you "copy straight from Azure to AWS".  There is a cost for transferring data over the Internet. You need to pay that regardless of whether you "copy straight from Azure to AWS". So, there is no difference in S3/Blob costs as a result of how you actually perform the copy.

Comment: I have put an update in the question

Comment: The second scenario has one less action, but the action you removed didn't cost much to begin with. Getting data out of Azure is what you pay for, and storing data in AWS in Azure is what you pay for. You do both in both scenarios. Storing data locally, and uploading it into AWS are almost free. However, the second scenario will save you some time, which may be relevant. It's entirely possible to move data from Azure to AWS, you're just distracting everyone with reasons that aren't valid.

Comment: So can you please explain like i have in a tabular form .. what costs what ?

Comment: To copy a file from Azure to AWS S3 bucket, you can use AzCopy to download the file from Azure storage to your local machine, and then use the AWS CLI to upload the file to S3. 
AzCopy does not support direct data transfer from Azure Storage to AWS S3. AzCopy is primarily designed for transferring data between local storage and Azure Storage or within Azure Storage services. Therefore, you can use AzCopy to copy the file from Azure to Blob storage, and then use the AWS CLI to copy the file to S3.

Comment: Here are the steps to copy the file from Azure to S3 using AzCopy and AWS CLI:

1.  Download and [install AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) and [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) on your local machine.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows -OutFile <path-to-download-location>\azcopy.zip

Comment: 2.  Use AzCopy to copy the file from Azure storage to Blob storage:

```
azcopy copy "https://<azure-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name>" "https://<azure-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-name>?<SAS-token>" --recursive=true

```

Replace  `<azure-storage-account-name>`,  `<container-name>`,  `<blob-name>`, and  `<SAS-token>`  with the appropriate values for your Azure storage account, container, blob, and SAS token. This command copies the file from Azure storage to Blob storage using the SAS token for authentication.

Comment: 3.  Use the AWS CLI to copy the file from Blob storage to S3:

```
aws s3 cp "s3://<bucket-name>/<object-key>" "<local-file-path>"

```

Replace  `<bucket-name>`  and  `<object-key>`  with the appropriate values for your S3 bucket and object, and  `<local-file-path>`  with the path to the local file where you want to save the downloaded file. This command copies the file from Blob storage to S3.

Comment: so what your saying is that i need to copy to a local drive first

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data pipeline in Azure Data Factory to copy data directly from Azure Blob Storage to AWS S3.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-simple-storage-service?tabs=data-factory

Comment: can i not do it all with az cmds ?

Comment: Yes, you can do everything with az cli that would be the DevOps way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way I can copy straight from Azure to AWS and have one cost?**

No. You are using two different services and each will charge you for their part of the copy process.

[Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/storage/blobs/#pricing) will charge you for:

- The request to GET the file
- The Data Transfer cost for sending data to the Internet

[AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) will charge you for:

- The request to PUT the file

Storage costs are charged "per GB month" based on how long you store the file. Thus, storage costs are not part of the cost of copying the file.